# laravel mongodb push element to existing array in document_

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel, push

In my mongodb collection I want to push some elements to an existing array. I use [jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB - Eloquent model and Query builder](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB) to work with lavavel and mongodb.

**How can I use the $push operator in jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB?**

#### MongoDB entry which shall be updated (RockMongo representation):

```js
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5328bc2627784fdb1a6cd398"),
   "comments": {
     "0": {
       "id": 3,
       "score": 8
    }
  },
   "created_at": ISODate("2014-03-18T21:35:34.0Z"),
   "file": {
     "file_id": NumberLong(1175),
     "timestamp": NumberLong(1395178534)
  }
}
```

---

#### Hint about array representation in rockmongo and mongo shell

[RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com) and [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/scripting/) array representation of the documents are a little bit different. Have a look at the `comments`-array. The above RockMongo representation appears in the mongo shell as:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5328c33a27784f3b096cd39b"), 
    "comments" : [  
     {  
        "id" : 3,  
        "score" : 8 
     } 
    ], 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-03-18T22:05:46Z"), 
    "file" : { 
        "file_id" : NumberLong(1176), 
        "timestamp" : NumberLong(1395180346) 
    } 
}
```

---

As the documentation states the `$push` operater to push elements to an array. This works fine in the mongo-shell:

#### Mongo shell

```sh
db.Images.update({'file.file_id': 1175}, 
   { $push: { comments: { id: 3, score: 8} } 
})
```

But in the query-builder I struggle to incorporate the $push operator. I get the error:

```
localhost:27017: Modified field name may not start with $
```

I did not find any documentation or example that showed me how to do it..

#### My jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB code, that returns the error

```php
// $file_id = 1175
public static function addComment( $file_id ) {  
    $image = Images::where( 'file.file_id', '=', floatval( $file_id ) )
    ->update( array('$push' => array( 'comments' => array( 'id' => 4, 'score' => 9 ) ) ) );
    return $image; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming everything is okay as it works in the shell then use the provided method to **push** instead:

```
Images::where('file.file_id', '=', floatval( $file_id ))
   ->push('comments', array( 'id' => 4, 'score' => 9 ));
```

Comment: in the mongo shell it works... so it should be an vaild array. I know that because before I had the problem that it was not an array, and then mongo complained with `Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array`. Anyway will test your suggestion.

Comment: @jerik Got that. There is a specific method for this. update only does the basic operations by itself

Comment: works perfect! thanks. Discovered as well that [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com) output is missleadig. Your comment about the structure hit correctly, as the same array entry is displayed in mongo shell as `"comments" : [  {  "id" : 3,  "score" : 8 } ]`, and in rockmongo as `"comments": { "0": { "id": 3, "score": 8 } }`. I used the representation of rockmongo for the posting.